# Scaling ImageView to size of a TextView in XML

Tags: android, layout, scaling

I have a TextView and a ImageView in a horizontal linear layout. Is it possible to scale the ImageView so that it is relative to the size of the TextView in the layout file?

Basically I want something like :-

[image]

Instead of something like this

[image]

The layout file would be

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ImageView height:matchparent, TextView height:wrapcontent, container LinearLayout height: wrap content ... maybe

Comment: try using image as leftdrawable of textview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, you can scale down the `ImageView` at the height relative to the `TextView`. To match the height of `TextView`, set `match_parent` to `android:layout_height` for `ImageView` which will help the `ImageView` to take the height of `TextView`. Try as follows...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also achieve the same result as below way...

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting a left compound drawable be more efficient?

Comment: Its possible...but he is asking that **Is it possible to scale the ImageView so that it is relative to the size of the TextView in the layout file?** Please, read the question properly.

Comment: you basicaly used what I wrote in comment :p

Comment: @DarkoRodic...I didn't even notice your comment ;)

Comment: @HamidShatu I read the question properly and interpreted what they wanted to achieve. It's bad for performance to have a heavy view hierarchy. Why use a LinearLayout instead of a compound drawable when a compound drawable is more efficient?

Comment: @BenPearson...Yeah, I agree with you. Personally, I will use compound drawable.

Comment: @BenPearson...I have updated my answer in accordance to your argue. Thanks for your concern. :)

Comment: @BenPearson How is it possible to achieve a left compound drawable that will scale to the size of the text?  The way compound drawables are implemented, the text can be scaled to the size of the image, but not the other way around.

Comment: any thoughts on how to produce the same result with a RelativeLayout? This solution works fine for LinearLayout but if i change it to a RelativeLayout the scaling doesn't work anymore

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

By using this you can simply add images inside your textview

```
<TextView>
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/picture.png"
</TextView>
```